# Internet Explorer 9 no longer recording History

Tags: internet-explorer-9, history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot view browser history in IE9](https://superuser.com/questions/294191/cannot-view-browser-history-in-ie9)

IE9 no longer records history.  It is set to record 20 days of history.  It stopped working last week, and only records visits on local intranet servers, and computer files.

I am on Windows 7 SP0.  Any ideas how to turn it back on?

Comment: Sorry, this is not an answer but I did not want to create another question when it has already been asked. I have the same problem. For some reason IE9 does not store browser history. The problem has existed ever since I upgraded. Despite resetting the IE settings, the problem persists. All I get is something like this (sorry for the link, I am not allowed to post images yet): http://i.stack.imgur.com/fYTFs.jpg

Comment: So you do have access to the internet? Well, at least to post this question..